# Convert SQL text to Linq command

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a textbox where the user will enter some SQL:

for example: `SELECT * FROM Customers;`

I know the LINQ will look something like this:

```
 var query = 
 from c in Customers.AsEnumerable()
 select c;
```

The problem I am having is that the user is going to enter a string, so I need
to convert this string into a LINQ command:

for eg.

How will I convert "`FROM`"  to from --> a text to a command.

In other words I will want something like:

```
 var query = 
 toCommand("from") c in Customers.AsEnumerable()
 toCommand("select") c;
```

**Forgot to mention that Customers is stored in a DataTable.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It depends how you'll execute that command...

Comment: Check this answer also:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5278555/1511796

Comment: Why are you using linq in this scenario? Why not to transfer this to SQL database?

Comment: Sorry,  just edited the question, I stored Customers in a DataTable, creating an In-Memory Database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661576/how-to-build-a-linq-query-from-text-at-runtime  (assuming the user will enter Linq queries, not SQL queries)

Comment: @Wasp thanks for the reply, I should have googled Dynamic Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but you probably need something along the lines of

```
var query = 
   from c in Customers
   where c.Name == usersuppliedstring
   select c;
```

Comment: Say the user enters "SELECT" in the textbox, I need to take this and convert it to the reserve word select, in other words i am letting the user build up the linq query, and the program to execute the query.